# Can I skip cutscenes in Snake Pass?

Tags: snake-pass

Several early levels in Snake Pass begin with an intro cutscene from Doodle the Hummingbird explaining the game's story. While these are charming the first time, they can be a bit annoying when replaying levels for hidden collectibles.

Is there any way to skip cutscenes in Snake Pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to skip cutscenes at this point and based on [the developer's own response to a request for this ability](https://steamcommunity.com/app/544330/discussions/0/1471966894859867892/#c1471966894865532252), it looks like this will not be added.

> Unfortunately, this isn't a feature we'll be bringing to the game I'm afraid. There are a few technical reasons as to why cutscenes were made unskippable. Because of this, it would be quite the task for us to actually look into making any such changes, so we'd like to focus on other cool stuff :) (more details soon...)